# Why is my proof of the strong law of large numbers incorrect?

Tags: probability

I was wondering where I have made a mistake in the following proof:

Let $(X_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of i.i.d random variables where $\mathbb E (|X_1|)<\infty$. Let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k$. Assume that $\mathbb E(X_1)=0$, since we can just replace $X_n$ with $X_n - \mathbb E(X_1)$. Then $\mathbb E(S_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb E(X_k)=0$ so $\mathbb E(S_n/n)=0$ hence $\sum_{n\ge 1}\mathbb E(S_n/n)=0$ so $\mathbb E(\sum_{n \ge 1} (S_n/n))=0$ so $\sum_{n \ge 1} (S_n/n)$ converges almost surely, so $S_n/n \to 0$ almost surely.

This is essentially the proof my lecturer gave but he looked at $\mathbb E (S_n^4)$ instead and it was a bit more complicated, and he had to make the additional assumption that $\mathbb E (X_1^4) < \infty$. I am not sure why my proof is wrong though.

Comment: Why are you allowed to interchange expectation and series?

Comment: @Math_QED I guess because the first series is convergent?

Comment: On Page 55 of http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~beresty/teach/pmnotes.pdf the sum is rearranged at the end. I assume this is valid, but in my case it is not. Why is that though?

Comment: First, please state what you are trying to prove in the beginning, not the end.  Second, I believe you mean that $\mathbb{E}(S_n)=\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb{E}(X_k)=0$.  Third, I do not understand why $\sum_{k=1}^n\mathbb{E}(X_k)=0$.

Comment: @Ben Yes, sorry. That is because each of the terms is 0.

Comment: Why are each of the terms zero?

Comment: Since I assumed this for X_1 at the beginning. Also the variables are I.i.d

Comment: Oh, quite right!  Oops : )

Comment: I'm rusty on stats. Do you mind explaining the last two steps for me?  You claim (1) $\mathbb{E}(\sum_{n\geq 1}S_n/n)=0$ implies that $\sum_{n\geq 1}S_n/n$ converges almost surely; and (2) these facts imply that $S_n/n$ converges almost surely to zero. I think I might have a shaky grasp on implication (1), but I do not understand implication (2) at all.

Comment: Well implication 2 is elementary. If a series converges then the limit of the summand must tend to 0. Implication 1 is just measure theory.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe for implication 1 I need the terms to be positive...

Comment: Merci!  You are correct, I missed the obvious in (2).  For some reason I was thinking that your claim was that $\sum S_n/n=0$, not $S_n/n\to 0$.  Go figure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot just switch expectation and summation (try it, for instance, with $f_k(x) = 1_{[k,k+1]}-1$).  In the comments, you write "the sum is rearranged at the end" of page 55, but it is not the same sum as the one you have.  There, the sum is of a series with *non-negative* terms whose series of expectations is convergent.  A well known theorem is implicitly used to justify convergence.

In general this is why even moments are used to prove large number type theorems with independence assumptions: even moments give rise to series with non-negative terms where elementary sum/integral exchange criteria can be applied.

Comment: Thank you. I understand